# SQL table objects

Tags: sql, oop, subquery

I am not sure if they call them objects, but on a Codecademy lesson [here](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/sql-table-transformation/lessons/subqueries/exercises/correlated-ii?action=lesson_resume) they used the letter f, but did not explain what the heck it was. 
Furthermore, if it is indeed an object, i.e. its copy as I understand, then how can they use the greater than conditions on the properties that are the same? Sorry to overwhelm so much. Please be so kind to explain.
The following is an excerpt from that lesson:

> For instance, assuming flight_id increments with each additional
>   flight, we could use the following query to view flights by carrier,
>   flight id, and sequence number:

```
SELECT carrier, id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM flights f
WHERE f.id < flights.id
AND f.carrier=flights.carrier) + 1
 AS flight_sequence_number
FROM flights;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an alias to the table so you can now reference `f.carrier` or `f.id` instead of using `flights.carrier` or `flights.id` in your subquery.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How about the condition part? `f.id<flights.id`

Comment: Only return rows where `f.id` is less than `flights.id`. Try changing the `<` to `>` or `=` (etc) and examine the results - it should help your understanding of it

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what is going on here is you have a main query

```
select ... from flights;
```

Inside that you have a subquery:

```
select ... from flights where ....;
```

The problem here is that the inner flights query needs to reference the outer one, so we rename the table here:

```
select ... from flights f where f. ... = flights. ...
```

This means that the inner query uses `f` to refer to the `flights` row and `flights` to reference the outer one.

In database terms we call these relations and we gave the inner table a locally scoped name.  Unlike in imperative languages, this entirely shadows the name at this point (`f` and `flights` refer to different rows in the same relation).